# What network topology could I implement in the scenario below?

Tags: networking, cisco

BatStateU PB Main II network Design is made up of the following

●   CEAFA Building is the network core that provides access to the internet using a router. A switch is being utilized to provide a connection for different switches in CICS Building, CIT Building, and SSC Building. Also, the server farm made up of email, web, and file servers are connected to this switch.

●   Each building has different users, such as students, Faculty, Staff, and guests.

●   Each building has a dedicated switch providing connectivity back to the switch in CEAFA.

●   The traffic of the user will be transferred to the core switch to access the resources from other buildings.

Suppose you are the Network Administrator of PB Main II suggest a network design that can be used to improve the BatStateU network. Consider the following parameters. Explain your answer and illustrate your design.
●   Network Redundancy

●   Failure Domains

●   VLAN

●   Routed Network

Answer (score 1):

The Hub would automatically be your bottleneck on the connection as with all those devices on one collision domain you will have all those devices fighting for time to speak.

Your best bet would be to get some newer switches to break up the collision domain into point-to-point domains where the switches can properly forward packets on the network.

Your next bet would be to use VLANS but that depends on how secure you want this network, VLANS on their own will not speed up a network, because you will need routing in between them, but from a security standpoint it would be ideal, as you can separate traffic out into their own broadcast domain.

With that, you can set up QOS on these VLANS if WAN bandwidth is limited.

Comment: I agree. Another possible step 2 (or a step 3) would be to track down workstations eating all the bandwidth.

Comment: thanks. i update the question rn any tips on how to do that tho?

Comment: your answers and any ideas would be a very big help to me :( ty in advance